# string validation in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a string validation function that I want to optimize. The string is of length `2n` and composed of `0` and `1`'s, for example, `str="100001"`. I want to test:

1) whether the number (has to be not less than 1) of `1`'s in oddly indexded positions in the string is equal to that in the evenly indexed positions

2) whether for every `StringTake[str,2*i]`, `i` runs from `1` to `n-1`, the number of `1`'s in oddly indexded positions in the string is not equal to that in the evenly indexed positions.

In sum, I want to test whether the position `2n` is **the first time** the number of `1`'s in oddly indexded positions in the string is equal to that in the evenly indexed positions.

`"100001"` and `101101` is a good string, but not `100100`, `100000` nor `000000`.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code does not test for invalid strings (characters not "0" or "1", length not even).

```
goodString[str_String] := Module[
  {digits, cumdiffs, pos},
  digits = Transpose[Partition[
    IntegerDigits[ToExpression[str], 10, StringLength[str]], 2]];
  cumdiffs = Subtract @@ Accumulate /@ digits;
  pos = Position[cumdiffs, 0, 1, 1];
  Length[pos] == 1 && pos[[1, 1]] == Length[cumdiffs]
]
```

Your examples:

```
goodString /@ {"100001" , "101101", "100100", "100000", "000000"}
```

Out[302]= {True, True, False, False, False}

There might be faster ways e.g. with NestList. Also if speed is a big issue and strings are likely to be long, you could split out the IntegerDigits[ToExpression[...]] in preprocessing and use Compile on the rest.

Daniel Lichtblau
Wolfram Research

Comment: Is OK the result for "000011"?

Comment: @belisarius That should give False, as the number of 1's is the same in the first even and first odd entry. The case where my code is wrong (could be special-cased) is "00". Claims True but violates rule that we require at least one 1.

Comment: I posted the comment and then realized it is so. But forgot to delete the comment. Sorry and thank you

Answer (score 1):

(Apologies for the schoolboy-code, this is my first effort with Strings in Mathematica, so I left in my thinking-as-I-went and also some commented-out debug/tracing values)

```
charcountsvec[s_String, c_String] := Table[
   If[StringTake[s, {i, i}] == c, 1, 0]
   , {i, 1, StringLength[s]}
];

oddchars[s_String] := StringTake[s, {1, -1, 2}]; (*pick out odd chars*)    
evenchars[s_String] := StringTake[s, {2, -1, 2}];

validatestr[str_String] :=     
 Block[{evencounts, oddcounts, answer1, answer2 (*, odds, evens*)},
  evencounts = Accumulate@charcountsvec[(*evens=*)evenchars[str], "1"];
  oddcounts = Accumulate@charcountsvec[(*odds=*)oddchars[str], "1"];
  (*my interpretation of "number of 1's in odd positions the same as in even positions"*)      
  answer1 = Last[oddcounts] == Last[evencounts]; 
  (*my interpretation of "for every..string...whether number of 1's in even/odd positions is not equal"*)      
  answer2 = Fold[And, True, 
    MapThread[Unequal, {Most[oddcounts], Most[evencounts]}]];

  {str, And[answer1, answer2](*,odds,evens,oddcounts,evencounts,answer1,answer2*)}
  ];
```

Testing:

```
validatestr/@{"100001","101101","100100","100000","000000"}
```

{{"100001", True}, {"101101", True}, {"100100", False}, {"100000", 
  False}, {"000000", False}}

```
validatestr["0000001"](*odd length string pukes, and returns False*)
```

During evaluation of (Local) In[428]:= MapThread::mptc: Incompatible dimensions of objects at positions {2, 1} and {2, 2} of MapThread[Unequal,{{0,0,0},{0,0}}]; dimensions are {3} and {2}. >>

(Local) Out[432]= {"0000001", False}